# ADVISE: "to offer advice to; counsel" vs. "to recommend; suggest"

Tags: meaning, verbs, synonyms, dictionaries

The American Heritage dictionary's entry for [advise](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=advise) reads

> 1. To offer advice to; counsel: *I **advised** him to study abroad; advised that we should reconsider the idea. How would you advise?*
> 2. To recommend; suggest: *I **advised** patience.*

In turn [recommend](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=recommend) reads

> 1. To praise or commend to another as being worthy/desirable; endorse: *I **recommended** him for the job; recommended a car instead of an SUV.*
> 2. To advise or counsel: *She **recommended** that we be on time. "recommended against signing an international agreement."*

I cannot fully grasp the difference between the first and second meanings of **advise**.

Comment: (1) You advise a person to pursue a certain course of action. (2) You advise a course of action [to a person].

Comment: Why did you include the definitions for "recommend"?

Comment: _ADVISE **2** : To recommend; suggest:_, and in turn RECOMMEND reads **2**: _To advise or counsel:_